# How to listen to/forward all ports on an interface, in Python or otherwise

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, ports, listen

I am writing an application, currently in Python + Twisted, which serves as a first port of call for DNS requests – if the requests meet certain patterns, e.g. Namecoin .bit addresses or OpenNIC TLDs, they are passed to different DNS resolvers, otherwise the default one is used.

Some addresses however I need redirected through special routes, e.g. Tor .onion addresses which don't resolve to traditional IPv4 addresses, or certain websites that require tunneling through a VPN for geolocation reasons. So when DNS requests for such sites come in, I want the application to create a new loopback interface/alias and return the IP of this interface. I then need to be able to tunnel all TCP and UDP traffic coming through this interface through the proxy/VPN or whatever to the endpoint it was set up for.

The question is, how can I do this? Listening on specific ports (e.g. 80) will be fine for most purposes, but as a perfectionist I would like to know how to accept connections/messages sent to ALL ports, without having to set up tens of thousands of listeners and potentially crashing the system.

Note: while everything is currently in Python, I don't mind adding components in C++ or another language, or playing around with network configurations to get this working.

Comment: Don't try to use Python for this.  Use iptables.

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface) for an example of iptables configuration.

Comment: What operating systems does this app support? What is the purpose of this application? It sounds like you're trying to do something security-sensitive and failing open might be a big problem.  There are a lot of answers to this question but the wrong one might make your application might do completely the wrong thing.

Comment: @Glyph I'm on Ubuntu Linux, this is (at least initially) just an application for personal use on my home computer – I think I already explained what it does in my question

Comment: If you're on linux, using iptables is probably the right call.  Also, you should look into tun/tap devices for creating more addresses for the DNS to map to, so that your server can dispatch on the IP address rather than the hostname for protocols that, unlike HTTP, don't include the hostname in their payload.